# $\mathbb A^n(k)$ and $\mathbb A^n(k)\setminus \{0\}$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field. Why $\mathbb A^n(k)$ and $\mathbb A^n(k)\setminus\{0\}$ (for $n>1$) are not homeomorphic with respect to the Zariski topology?

Comment: By $k^n$ do you mean $k \times \ldots \times k$ or $\mathbb{A}_k^n$?

Comment: He means the affine space.

Comment: For $n=1$ they *are* homeomorphic. So you should add the assumption $n>1$.

Comment: Is the scheme $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ the soberificiation of $k^n$? In that case a homeomorphism $k^n \cong k^n \setminus \{0\}$ would induce a homeomorphism $\mathbb{A}^n_k \cong \mathbb{A}^n_k \setminus \{0\}$ and perhaps more invariants from scheme theory would be available. But I even have no idea for the case $n=2$ and $k=\mathbb{C}$ ...

Comment: Related (thanks to another user for pointing this out): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78771/is-mathbbc2-homeomorphic-to-mathbbc2-0-0-with-the-zariski-topolog

Comment: But what about the fundamental groups? Can this approach be helpful?

Answer (score 6):

**(This is not an answer, and everything that follows below was originally prompted by the fact that the O.P. did not exclude the case $n=1$ in his question when he first asked it, which he has now done at a later edit.)**

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Then the Zariski topology on $k$ is the finite complement topology, and similarly on $k- \{0\}$. Note that two spaces with finite complement topology are homeomorphic iff they have the space cardinality. In this case both $k$, $k - \{0\}$ have the same cardinality. So, they are in fact homeomorphic in the Zariski topology. In particular, I am not sure your statement is true.

What I wrote above may not illustrate just how weak the Zariski topology is. For a better example you can try to show that any two curves in $\mathbb{C}^2$, where by a curve I mean the zero set of an irreducible polynomial, are homeomorphic in the Zariski topology.

What is true though is that $k^n - \{0\}$ is not affine for $n \geq 2$. But, this question has been asked on MSE before. Just look for it. **(Later addition: Note that as the user below pointed out, this does not imply that $k^n$ and $k^n - \{0\}$ are not homeomorphic. My comment about them not being affine was not meant as an argument for them not being homeomorphic.)**

Here is a related mathoverflow link where Greg Kuperberg attempts to answer the question for $n = 2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (thanks are completely due to another user for pointing this out to me who I cannot locate at the moment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78771/is-mathbbc2-homeomorphic-to-mathbbc2-0-0-with-the-zariski-topolog).

Finally, I asked some algebraic geometers at my institution, and they do not seem to be aware of this being a result.

Comment: I'd like a proof which doesn't invokes the fact that $k^n\setminus \{0\}$ is not affine.

Comment: Dear @Galoisfan: But, my proof doesn't invoke the fact that $k - \{0\}$ is not affine. I just use the Zariski topology.

Comment: The fact $k^n -\{ 0\}$ being not affine means that there is no rational isomorphism $k^n-\{0\} \rightarrow {\mathbb A}^r$. It is not clear that it implies that there is no homeomorphism.

Comment: @Rankeya: although you did not like my argument refering to spectral spaces, I restate it here: since $k^n\setminus 0$ for $n>1$ is not affine, it cannot be a spectral space, which is a purely topological property -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space  I guess the problem lies in the behaviour of quasi-compact, open sets -- thus giving the opportunity to give a direct proof by contradiction.

Comment: Dear @Hagen: as the wikipedia article says, being spectral means being homeomorphic to spec of a ring (does this also imply being isomorphic to spec of a ring as ringed spaces). Not being affine means not being isomorphic as ringed spaces to spec of a ring. But, it could still be homeomorphic to spec of a ring right? Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hagen, your first inference is incorrect: a space may not be an affine variety yet still be homeomorphic to one, cf. $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: I wonder why this "answer" has so many upvotes. It doesn't answer the question. It is merely a long comment.

Comment: @Martin, what can I say, I'm a sheep :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: While I don't know why my answer received so many upvotes, and while you are perfectly entitled to downvote the answer, your comment implies that my "answer" was not worth the upvotes, and I find that a little rude (you could have just downvoted the answer). But, to each his own, and I would be very interested if you have an answer for the general case as I find your answers to usually be illuminating!

Comment: When I read answers with many upvotes on math.SE, I usually assume that it contains a good and reliable answer to the question. I think this is also what upvotes are for, right? But when people upvote answers just because they are interesting in their own right, or perhaps for other reasons I don't want to mention here, this system breaks down. When one reads this question here superficially then one might get the impression that it is already answered, but it is not. My advice is to delete this "answer" here and to replace it by a comment. But of course, it's your own choice.